# Python: translating a printing recursive function into a generator

Tags: python, recursion, generator, towers-of-hanoi

I have found this function:

```
def hanoi(pegs, start, target, n):
    assert len(pegs[start]) >= n, 'not enough disks on peg'
    if n == 1:
        pegs[target].append(pegs[start].pop())
        print '%i -> %i: %s' % (start, target, pegs)
    else:
        aux = 3 - start - target  # start + target + aux = 3
        hanoi(pegs, start, aux, n-1)
        hanoi(pegs, start, target, 1)
        hanoi(pegs, aux, target, n-1)
```

At [Trying to implement recursive Tower of Hanoi algorithm with arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581683/trying-to-implement-recursive-tower-of-hanoi-algorithm-with-arrays) here on StackOverflow.

Now I need to modify this so that instead of the `start, target, pegs` being printed, the `pegs` variable is yielded out each iteration.

For example I expect this output out of the new function (pretty printed):

```
>>> list( hanoi([[120, 90, 60, 30], [], []]) )
[ [[120, 90, 60], [30], []],
  [[120, 90], [30], [60]],
  [[120, 90], [], [60, 30]],
  [[120], [90], [60, 30]],
  [[120, 30], [90], [60]],
  [[120, 30], [90, 60], []],
  [[120], [90, 60, 30], []],
  [[], [90, 60, 30], [120]],
  [[], [90, 60], [120, 30]],
  [[60], [90], [120, 30]],
  [[60, 30], [90], [120]],
  [[60, 30], [], [120, 90]],
  [[60], [30], [120, 90]],
  [[], [30], [120, 90, 60]],
  [[], [], [120, 90, 60, 30]],
]
```

This is how I tried to modify it:

```
def hanoi(pegs, start, target, n):
    assert len(pegs[start]) >= n, 'not enough disks on peg'
    if n == 1:
        pegs[target].append(pegs[start].pop())
        yield pegs
    else:
        aux = 3 - start - target  # start + target + aux = 3
        hanoi(pegs, start, aux, n-1)
        hanoi(pegs, start, target, 1)
        hanoi(pegs, aux, target, n-1)
```

But, (input pegs numbers are a bit bigger because of graphical purposes):

```
>>> pegs = [[120, 90, 60, 30], [], []]
>>> print(list(hanoi(pegs, 0, 2, 4)))
[]
```

The output is just an empty list.

Trying to make copies of the lists via `[:]` did not help, and I am left very confused, maybe `print` can always print out, but `yield` gets "stuck" inside deep recursion levels, so it is yielded to less deep recursion and not to the `outside`. Also using a list with `append` does not work:

```
def hanoi(pegs, start, target, n):
    assert len(pegs[start]) >= n, 'not enough disks on peg'
    out = []
    if n == 1:
        pegs = pegs[:]
        pegs[target].append(pegs[start].pop())
        out.append( pegs )
    else:
        aux = 3 - start - target  # start + target + aux = 3
        hanoi(pegs, start, aux, n-1)
        hanoi(pegs, start, target, 1)
        hanoi(pegs, aux, target, n-1)
    return out
```

I also tried following advice from [Python: using a recursive algorithm as a generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248830/python-using-a-recursive-algorithm-as-a-generator)

```
def hanoi(pegs, start, target, n):
    assert len(pegs[start]) >= n, 'not enough disks on peg'
    if n == 1:
        pegs = pegs[:]
        pegs[target].append(pegs[start].pop())
        yield pegs
    else:
        aux = 3 - start - target  # start + target + aux = 3
        for i in hanoi(pegs, start, aux, n-1): yield i
        for i in hanoi(pegs, start, target, 1): yield i
        for i in hanoi(pegs, aux, target, n-1): yield i
```

By yielding from nested `for` loops, but it failed.

How can I write such generator (that I need for graphical purposes)?

The generator will be used like this:

```
pegs = [[120, 90, 60, 30], [], []]
positions = hanoi(pegs, 0, 2, 4)

for position in positions:
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255)) 

    print(index, peg_history[index])
    for i, pegs in enumerate(position):
        display_pegs(pegs, 100 + 180*i, 300, screen)
    pygame.display.update()
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a generator version could look like this:

```
def hanoi_yield(pegs, start, target, n):
    # pegs will be modified!
    assert len(pegs[start]) >= n, 'not enough disks on peg'

    if n == 1:
        pegs[target].append(pegs[start].pop())
        yield pegs
    else:
        aux = 3 - start - target  # start + target + aux = 3
        yield from hanoi_yield(pegs, start, aux, n-1)
        yield from hanoi_yield(pegs, start, target, 1)
        yield from hanoi_yield(pegs, aux, target, n-1)

pegs = [[120, 90, 60, 30], [], []]
for item in hanoi_yield(pegs, 0, 2, 4):
    print(item)
```

with the output:

```
[[120, 90, 60], [30], []]
[[120, 90], [30], [60]]
[[120, 90], [], [60, 30]]
[[120], [90], [60, 30]]
[[120, 30], [90], [60]]
[[120, 30], [90, 60], []]
[[120], [90, 60, 30], []]
[[], [90, 60, 30], [120]]
[[], [90, 60], [120, 30]]
[[60], [90], [120, 30]]
[[60, 30], [90], [120]]
[[60, 30], [], [120, 90]]
[[60], [30], [120, 90]]
[[], [30], [120, 90, 60]]
[[], [], [120, 90, 60, 30]]
```

the only 'trick' here is to `yield from hanoi_yield` because `hanoi_yield` is a generator.

the down-side: this returns a reference to the same list all the time and changes the input list `pegs` (which is just the return value)! that may not be wished or useful... more below:

---

a version that does not change the first argument (`pegs`) and returns an individual list every time (and can therefore be used in the `list` constructor). i had to add an auxiliary variable `_work_pegs` as the algorithm needs to change the this list. `pegs` is now unchanged. i also `yield` a `deepcopy` of the result (we are handling lists of lists here; a regular copy would not work):

```
from copy import deepcopy

def hanoi_yield(pegs, start, target, n, _work_pegs=None):

    if _work_pegs is None:
        _work_pegs = deepcopy(pegs)
        # or (this way pegs could be a tuple of tuples):
        # _work_pegs = [list(item) for item in pegs]

    assert len(_work_pegs[start]) >= n, 'not enough disksdef on peg'

    if n == 1:
        _work_pegs[target].append(_work_pegs[start].pop())
        yield deepcopy(_work_pegs)
        # or (returning tuples might be nice...):
        # yield tuple(tuple(item) for item in _work_pegs)
    else:
        aux = 3 - start - target  # start + target + aux = 3
        yield from hanoi_yield(pegs, start, aux, n-1, _work_pegs)
        yield from hanoi_yield(pegs, start, target, 1, _work_pegs)
        yield from hanoi_yield(pegs, aux, target, n-1, _work_pegs)
```

finally this works:

```
pegs = [[120, 90, 60, 30], [], []]
lst = list(hanoi_yield(pegs, 0, 2, 4))
print(lst)
```

Comment: I tried your version (using explicit `for` because I am in Python 2 but i got `>>>pegs = [[120, 90, 60, 30], [], []]`
`>>>print(list(hanoi(pegs, 0, 2, 4)))`
`[[[], [], [120, 90, 60, 30]], [[], [], [120, 90, 60, 30]], [[], [], [120, 90, 60, 30]], [[], [], [120, 90, 60, 30]], [[], [], [120, 90, 60, 30]], [[], [], [120, 90, 60, 30]], [[], [], [120, 90, 60, 30]], [[], [], [120, 90, 60, 30]], [[], [], [120, 90, 60, 30]], [[], [], [120, 90, 60, 30]], [[], [], [120, 90, 60, 30]], [[], [], [120, 90, 60, 30]], [[], [], [120, 90, 60, 30]], [[], [], [120, 90, 60, 30]], [[], [], [120, 90, 60, 30]]]`

Comment: That is calling `list` is not working as intended, how could I fix that?

Comment: I understand that Python treats lists in a counter-intuitive way, pointing to outdated objects, so you need to `yield a deepcopy of the restult (we are handling lists of lists here; a regular copy would not work):` but why did this problem only show when using `list` and not when traversing the items one by one?

Comment: the first version changed (the global) `pegs` all the time. there was only 1 list in play while the function was called again and again; you could watch its evolution with the print statement. if you `print(id(item), item)` in the first version you see, that you always print the same list - just its content has changed now. `list(...)` then generated a list with several references to the same list inside.

Comment: Thanks hiro, for the detailed explanation (I suggest you move it into the answer as comments are temporary and may be deleted). Just to double check, I understood that this very similar to C pointers, I point to a list into memory, and yield always that same object, but its contents vary and in the end all pointers refer to the same collection of values. Correct?

Comment: @Caridorc: yes, that is correct! made some small adaptions to my answer; feel free to change things to your liking if you feel something is missing or unclear. grazie e buona notte!

Comment: Buona notte, gentile compatriota :)